# Add Ellipse image on button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to add ellipse image on `Button`. But when i  add image on `Button` the `Background` color of `Button` lost. What can i do ?

```
<Button Height="80" Width="130" 
                    BorderThickness="0">
                <Label Content="Stephen King" FontFamily="Gabriola" FontSize="20"
                       Margin="0,30,0,0"></Label>
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>

                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Ellipse Height="70" Width="70" Grid.Column="1">
                            <Ellipse.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Icons/stephen.jpg"/>
                            </Ellipse.Fill>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>

                <Button.Background>

                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >

                        <GradientStop Color="#26C885" Offset="0" />

                        <GradientStop Color="#109489" Offset="1.0" />

                    </LinearGradientBrush>

                </Button.Background>
            </Button>
```

Wanted : 
[image]

But result :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wpf controls are lookless.

What that means is they have fixed behaviour but variable "look".  That variable look is handled by templating.  Setting a control's template completely changes what it is.

Your markup replaces the border and stuff that usually make up a button with an ellipse. It has no background to show the background.

This lookless nature of wpf controls is kind of weird if you've done any other development. You can read it explained any number of  times and still not "get" the implications.

This article here is intended to help beginners with that:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29866.aspx

Notice all the markup there which is the regular control template for a button.

It's difficult to work out what you intend to do with this button.

If you're going to use it for many buttons with different pictures etc then you should either subclass button and add dependency properties or define a class with attached properties. In either case you'd probably want a template used those dependency properties so you could bind the imagesource.

The way to work on a control's template is to extract the default one. ( The above link explains how to do that ). Take a long look at the template it gives you. Any named parts need to be retained somehow or you risk losing functionality. As Chris says, the button is a contentcontrol and you need a content presenter in your new template somewhere if you still want any content to work.

You don't seem to have any content, so maybe you don't need that.

Another complication here is that ellipse which is sort of sticking out the top of where you'd usually expect a button to end.
You'll need to leave space for that in the layout where you use the button or use fairly advanced techniques.

You could push the ellipse into the adorner decorator layer and on top of any other window content.

Or

You could go quick n dirty.

I don't have your picture, so I've just set the ellipse fill to red here:

```
    <Button Height="90"
            Width="200">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" >
                <GradientStop Color="#26C885" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#109489" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Height="60"
                     Width="60"
                     Fill="Red"
                     >
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                     <TranslateTransform Y="-40" />
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            </Ellipse>
            <TextBlock Text="Stephen King" 
                       FontFamily="Gabriola" 
                       FontSize="20"
                       Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Button>
```

The rendertransform pushes the ellipse up and out the control.

[image]

Paste that into a window, spin it up.

Mouse over the button.

Note the background (of the border) turns light blue on mouse over as a visual cue to the user that this is a button they can click.

This still works because I've not replaced the button's template.

Note also the use of TextBlock.

Where you'd use a label in winforms or html you usually use a TextBlock in wpf.  The wpf label is not equivalent to a label in other technologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a template and you want the template to render the additional content specified in the target control, then you need to include a `ContentPresenter` in the template to specify where in the template the content should be rendered. Within the `ControlTemplate` this will need to be placed in a `Grid` or similar. You will also need to move the gradient background etc. to the template since the template completely takes over the rendering of the target control.

If this is a one off button, then just move your rendering into a `Button.Content` element.